# How to display report file in github using netlify?

Tags: github, netlify

I want to display testing report file in `checks` tab in github when create the pull request in github. I have buit the website through netlify. I only see the number of files that are generated or changed. I want to see that files in github when deploying using netlify.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about the detail you're aiming for here, but you will eventually, somewhere during the build process, need to call out to the [GitHub Checks API](https://developer.github.com/v3/checks/). You'll also have to fit the reporting to what the API accepts as parameters. So you might also have to do some data processing of the testing report before calling out the API.

I hope this helps, I would need more detail about the `build` part to offer more assistance.